# How to close pop up in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, web, webdriver

I am trying to close pop up using selenium web driver with java. I have tried different ways, but unable to succeed. Please help me.

```
package Demo; 
import java.util.Set;

import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class YahooTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        FirefoxDriver obj = new FirefoxDriver();
        String url = "https://www.planyourjourney.com/";
        obj.get(url);
        obj.manage().window().maximize();
        obj.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[12]/div/div/div[9]")).click();
        obj.findElementByClassName("dyna-link-new-registration").click();
        obj.findElement(By.linkText("B2B Login")).click();
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        obj.findElement(By.id("userid")).clear();
        obj.findElement(By.id("userid")).sendKeys("1592jet@gmail.com");
        obj.findElement(By.id("ulPassword")).clear();
        obj.findElement(By.id("ulPassword")).sendKeys("spyj01");
        obj.findElement(By.name("Next")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        obj.findElement(By.id("affilitetrainadvpage"));
        Alert alert = obj.switchTo().alert();
        alert.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly you've tried? Provide your `Java` code as well as `HTML` for pop-up

Comment: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5310/how-to-close-pop-up-window-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Please format your code. It's not readable like this.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the source code of the web page and could not find any alert in it.

The pop-up is actually written inside a div tag.

Hence, remove the codes related to alert and use below code which uses xpath.

```
obj.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='affilitetrainadvpage']/span/a/img")).click();
```

Comment: It is working for me. I am using chrome. Can you check in it. Are you getting any error.